# Windows10で好きなユーザー名を指定するには？

Tags: windows-10

新しいWindows 10のパソコンを買って、自分のMicrosoftアカウントにサインすると、ユーザー名は氏名のローマ字の最初の５文字から勝手に指定されます。例えば、「ボコフグレブ」と場合、`bokof`になり、「徳川武」の場合、`tokug`になってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ユーザー名をローマ字にしなければいけないなら、せめて`TokugawaTakehsi`や`Tokugawa_Takeshi`の様にに分かりやすく指定したいです。しかし、単にフォルダー名を`tokug`から`TokugawaTakehsi`に変えても良い訳ではありません（そもそも`ユーザー/**`にとって名前変更が不可能になっています）。

どうすれば宜しいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ネットワークに接続出来ない状態にして購入後初回起動や再インストールを行うとローカルアカウント作成画面になるので、そこで任意の名前を入力すれば好きなユーザー名を作成できます。
ただし出来るとしても長い名前や記号を含むのはやめておいた方が良さそうです。

既にMicrosoftアカウントでサインインしてしまっている場合は、必要なデータのバックアップやソフトウェアの再インストールが出来るようにしてから、Windowsをクリーンな状態に再インストールすれば良いでしょう。

参考記事：
[Windows 10の初期化時にMicrosoftアカウントでの強制サインインを回避する方法 (ローカルアカウントを作成する方法)](https://little-beans.net/exposition/win10-setup-1903/)
[ローカルアカウントを作れないクリーンインストール後のWindows10 Home（1909）](https://ikt-s.com/local-account1909/)
[Windows10 のインストールでローカルアカウントが作成できない時の対処法](https://www.pasoble.jp/windows/10/setup-local-account.html)

---

その後、ネットワークに接続出来る状態にしてからMicrosoftアカウントでのサインインに切り替えれば使い勝手は変わらないでしょう。

[Windows10でローカルユーザをマイクロソフトアカウントへ紐づける方法](https://www.wannko.net/windows10/etc/microac.html)

---

ユーザーやフォルダーが増えて複数ある状態でも構わないなら、ローカルアカウントを追加で作成して切り替えるという方法もあるでしょう。

[Windows10 – Microsoftアカウントをローカルアカウントに変更（切替）](https://pc-karuma.net/windows10-switch-local-account-from-microsoft-account/)

Comment: パソコンの初期設定の時インターネットと接続せずにローカルアカウント作成という方法でいけました。御回答に感謝します。